# How to use if else condition using mathfilters in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a question, I'm doing a project in Django and there is a part of the application called Pagos(payments), there I show the following: payments made, total_pagos(total payment) and pending payment.

To show the information of these payments I'm using [`mathfilters`](https://pypi.org/project/django-mathfilters/) because addition and subtraction are used in my templates.

For the template it's showing the information properly, only the problem comes when I want to use conditionals since once pending payment is equal to 0.00 it means that the client already pays everything and must show a text that says “PAGADO” (paid), when pending payment it has another number than 0.00 must show a label that says “PENDIENTE” (pending).

This is the code that I am using and it works, since it shows me the result of the costo_servicio (amount of the service) cost minus the total_pagos (total payments), whatever it shows is the pending payment, it can show several numbers or 0.00:

```
{% for juicio in juicios %}                                                            
       {{ juicio.costo_servicio|sub:total_pagos }}
{% endfor %}
```

But if I put this, it doesn't show the if and therefore doesn't do the subtraction or show the text PAGADO(paid):

```
{% for juicio in juicios %}
  {% if juicio.costo_servicio|sub:total_pagos == 0.00 %}
    {{ juicio.costo_servicio|sub:total_pagos }}
    <td class="text-right"><span class="saldo-pagado" ><strong>PAGADO</strong></span></td>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I'll share you the rest of my models and my views:

juicios models.py

```
class Juicios(models.Model):
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    no_expediente_cv = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    costo_servicio=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

pagos models.py

```
class Pagos(models.Model):
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)   
    monto_pago=models.IntegerField()
```

pagos view.py

```
def PagosDetalle(request, cliente_id):
    context = {}
    cliente = Cliente.objects.get(id=cliente_id)
    pagos = Pagos.objects.filter(cliente=cliente_id)
    juicios = Juicios.objects.filter(cliente=cliente_id)
    total_pagos = Pagos.objects.filter(cliente=cliente).aggregate(sum_of_all_orders=Sum('monto_pago'))
    pagos_filtrados=Pagos.objects.filter(cliente=cliente)

    context["pagos"] = pagos
    context["pagos_filtrados"] = pagos_filtrados
    context["total_pagos"] = total_pagos['sum_of_all_orders']
    if juicios:
        context["juicios"] = juicios

    return render(request, "pagos-detalle.html",context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`with`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with) tag to store the result of the calculation in a template variable, for example:

```
{% with juicio.costo_servicio|sub:total_pagos as result %}
  {% if result == 0 %}
     ...
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```